# jquery toggle between forms

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have ran out of ideas for this assignment for a class. I had to create two PHP forms using PHP_SELF and I am suppose to use javascript or jquery to toggle between the forms. I tried using

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('form2').style.display = 'hidden';">Form 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'hidden'; document.getElementById('form2').style.display = 'block';">Form 2</a>
```

This does work on changing the forms, however when I hit the submit button the form it goes back to form 1 and doesn't display the results. The thing I have to figure out is after the form has been submitted using PHP_SELF, how to get it to stay on that form to show the results generated by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a hidden field to the form called `formId` and have PHP echo it back, so that you know from Javascript which form's results you're reading:

```
<?php
    ...
    if (isset($_POST['formId']))
    {
        $show = 'form1' == $_POST['formId'] ? 'form1' : 'form2';
        $hide = 'form1' == $_POST['formId'] ? 'form2' : 'form1';
        // This PHP must be inside the Javascript section of the page, at end.
        print <<<SETVISIBILITY

\$('#$show').style.display = 'block'; // Should be unnecessary (?)
\$('#$hide').style.display = 'hidden';

SETVISIBILITY;
    }
?>
```

Or you can do the SUBMIT and result display all in jQuery, so that you needn't reload the page losing your form visibilities.

Comment: I like the form ID idea, I will try that. The next assignment is using all Jquery, however for this one I have to use PHP for the forms and Jquery to toggle them. Don't ask why, cause I ask the same question!

Comment: Oh well, then just add `if (isset($_POST['formID']))`... and when your reload the page after the POST, you add (from PHP) a jQuery command to set the visibility properly.

Comment: what would be an example of that? Both of my forms have hidden fields with the name formID and an id of formID with different values. At the bottom of my page I put if (isset($_POST['formID'])); how do I get jquery to pick up on what ID is being used?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use something like this

```
if($_POST){
//display success message here
}else{
//display form here
}
```